# can I do submethods in ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

I know you can't do nested methods in ruby, what I Want to know can I do something like:

```
attr_reader :dimensions

def dimensions.seprate
  [self.dimensions[0],self.dimensions[1]]
end
```

and then I can use it like

```
x,y = bar.dimensions.seprate
```

just as a way to semantically refer to helper methods that are related to one another.

would that work?

ff not is there away to do that or something like that?

Comment: not yet, but I was curios if it work or not.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  If `dimensions` is an Array, then `[dimensions[0],dimensions[1]]` is no different from `dimensions` itself.  Unless it's more than two elements, but then `separate` is a lousy name for that submethod.

Comment: rails or ruby doesn't like it, just throws a "unrecognised variable or method" error. I guess you can't do stuff like that then.

Comment: You can't do nested methods, but sometimes I do something similar using `Proc.new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I don't understand the specific example.  But in general, if you want to do `obj.meth1.meth2`, then `obj.meth1` has to return an object that has a method named `meth2`.  There are no 'context-aware' methods in Ruby such that the return value of `meth1` could have an extra method only have because it's being returned by a method of `obj`.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I've put a comment in, It's not possible to what I'm asking, ruby just throws errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby will already assume something like:

```
x,y = arr
```

Means the same as:

```
x = arr[0]
y = arr[1]
```

So I don't think you have to do anything. In other words:

```
x,y = bar.dimensions
```

If the type of "dimensions" is more complex than an array, this might not work, but it probably just needs to respond to the [] method...

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfectly valid name for a method. It is however not a valid Ruby identifier.

```
define_method(:'dimensions.separate') do
  [dimensions[0], dimensions[1]]
end

x, y = bar.send(:'dimensions.separate')
```

Comment: interesting, not what i'm looking for but interesting none the less.